# How to recursively print all words in a trie in C

Tags: c, struct, trie

I am trying to write a function that prints all words in a trie in C. I've tried lots of different methods, but I'm not getting any output.

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct TNode
{
  char letter;
  struct TNode * children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
  int count; 
}TNode;
```

Here is my method to create the trie. It takes a url, creates a char array from the words on the web page, and makes a trie from the array.

```
TNode * indexPage(const char* url)
{
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //Holds the characters from the webpage.
  TNode * root;             //The root node of the trie.
  TNode * hold;             //Temporarily holds the node to be added to the trie.
  int charsRead;            //The number of characters read from the webpage.
  int i, j;                 

  charsRead = getText(url, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

  //Convert all uppercase letters to lowercase in buffer.
  for(i = 0; i < charsRead; ++i)
  {
    if((buffer[i] >= 'A') && (buffer[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
      //Lowercase characters are 32 greater than uppercase, and 
      //the 'space' ASCII character equals 32.
      buffer[i] += ' ';
    }
  }
  buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';

  //Initialize the root TNode.
  root = (TNode *)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
  root->letter = 0;
  root->count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    root->children[i] = NULL;
  }

  //Create the trie.
  hold = root;
  for(i = 0; i < charsRead; ++i)
  {
    if((buffer[i] >= 'a') && (buffer[i] <= 'z'))
    {
      for(j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++j)
      {
        if(hold->children[j] == NULL)
        {
          hold->children[j] = (TNode *)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
          hold->children[j]->letter = buffer[i];
          hold->children[j]->count = 0;
          int x;
          for(x = 0; x < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++x)
          {
            hold->children[j]->children[x] = NULL;
          }
          hold = hold->children[j];
          break;
        }
        else if(hold->children[j]->letter == buffer[i])
        {
          hold = hold->children[j];
          if((buffer[i + 1] < 'a') || (buffer[i + 1] > 'z'))
          {
            ++(hold->count);
            hold = root;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return root;
  }
```

I've made sure that the getText function is correctly filling the buffer and returning the number of characters it read from the web page.

Here is the print method I'm trying without success:

```
void printTrieContents(TNode * root, char * buffer, int buffIndex)
{
  if(root == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  if(root->count != 0)
  {
    printf("\t%s\n", buffer);
  }
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    if(root->children[i] != NULL)
    {
      buffer[buffIndex] = root->children[i]->letter;
      printTrieContents(root->children[i], buffer, buffIndex + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Many of the pages I found on this had the trie created in alphabetical order, but I have to print out the words in the order that they appear on the page. If anyone could give me a suggestion, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: A `trie` should implement a tree in an array. That requires that your elements of the array has something to build actually an order like a `left` and a `right` pointer, index, or something similar to reference other array elements. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trie)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-display-content/

Comment: There are quite a few problems in your code. Like for example not using the [standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) or terminating your buffer.

Comment: In the non-root nodes, should `count` be initialized to 1 instead of 0?

Comment: In `printTrieContents` you probably need `buffer[buffIndex + 1] = '\0';` before recursing.

Comment: This makes zero sense. None, zilch, nada. If  you need to print words as they appear on the page, just print them as you are reading the page. You don't need a trie for that. A trie is a dictionary. You don't use a dictionary to reconstruct the text it was compiled from, dictionaries are not designed to do that.

Comment: The entire point of the program is to use a trie, so your comment actually makes zero sense. None, zilch, nada.

Comment: Programs are usually made to perform useful tasks. That's their entire point. *Using a trie* is not a useful task, it's a means to an end. Unless you are doing your school assignment or doing some other kind of exercise, that is. The whole point of *an exercise* might be to use a trie. Is it an assignment? Post it in its entirety verbatim.

Comment: Aside, why assume 32? Code could use `buffer[i] += 'a' - 'A';`.   `buffer[i] += topper((unsigned char) buffer[i]);` is even better and no `if((buffer[i] >= 'A') && (buffer[i] <= 'Z'))` needed.

Answer (score 0):

A trie is nothing but an efficiently organised alphabetically sorted list. Like any alphabetically sorted list, it remembers nothing about the original order of its creation. It's alphabetically sorted. Let's look an alphabetically sorted list. (It is utterly unimportant how it is represented, with a trie or in any other way).

```
brown
dog
fox
jumps
lazy
over
quick
the
```

What text was it built from? Who knows. Maybe "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". Maybe "dog? dog lazy. fox? fox brown. the jumps? the jumps quick. over". Maybe out of any of an infinite number of other texts. We have no idea.

We can graft additional data onto the list (again, doesn't matter if it's a trie or anything else). The data may contain some information about the order of insertion. Let's try that:

```
brown [3]
dog [9]
fox [4]
jumps [5]
lazy [8]
over [6]
quick [2]
the [1,7]
```

This is already something, but is it much? What is needed to reconstruct the original text? It looks like we need to extract the numbers, pair them with words, put the pairs in (for example) an array, and sort them using numbers as keys. Does the alphabetical structure of the list help us? Not a single bit. Does the fact that all occurrences of the same word are kept together? Not a single bit. Why did we keep it alphabetical? For sake of using an alphabetical list? OK well then, we have used an alphabetical list for comically inefficient and useless intermediate storage. If that's the purpose of this exercise, then we have achieved it.

*And one more time, it doesn't matter whether the alphabetically sorted list is organised as a trie or as anything else*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I changed my code so that it creates the trie in alphabetical order. I'm actually getting output now, but it's not the words on the webpage. It's just jibberish. I feel like I'm close now, but I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I changed the struct to this:

```
typedef struct TNode
{
  struct TNode * children[ALPHABET_SIZE]; //Children nodes
  int count;    //Word count
}TNode;
```

Here is the function to make the trie:

```
TNode * indexPage(const char* url)
{
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
  TNode * root;             
  TNode * hold;             
  int charsRead;            
  int i, j;                    

  charsRead = getText(url, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

  //printf("%s\n",buffer);

  //Convert all uppercase letters to lowercase in buffer.
  for(i = 0; i < charsRead; ++i)
  {
    if((buffer[i] >= 'A') && (buffer[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
      buffer[i] += ' ';
    }
  }

  //Initialize the root TNode.
  root = (TNode *)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
  root->count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    root->children[i] = NULL;
  }

  //Create the trie.
  hold = root;
  for(i = 0; i < charsRead; ++i)
  {
    if((buffer[i] >= 'a') && (buffer[i] <= 'z'))
    {
      if(hold->children[(buffer[i] - 'a')] == NULL)
      {
        hold->children[(buffer[i] - 'a')] = (TNode *)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
        hold->children[(buffer[i] - 'a')]->count = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++j)
        {
          hold->children[(buffer[i] - 'a')]->children[j] = NULL;
        }
      }
      if((buffer[i + 1] < 'a') || (buffer[i + 1] > 'z'))
      {
        ++(hold->count);
        hold = root;
      }
      else
      {
        hold = hold->children[(buffer[i] - 'a')];
      }
    }
  }

  //Return the pointer to the trie.
  return root;
}
```

Here's the function to print all the words in the trie:

```
void printTrieContents(TNode * root, char * buffer, int buffIndex)
{
  int i;
  if(root == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  if(root->count != 0)
  {
    buffer[buffIndex + 1] = '\0';
    printf("\t%s\n",buffer);
    buffIndex = 0;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    if(root->children[i] != NULL)
    {
      buffer[buffIndex] = i + 'a';
      printTrieContents(root->children[i], buffer, buffIndex + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

If I use say a web page containing a pdf (https://www.constitution.org/us_doi.pdf), I get a jumbled up output like this:

```
...        
bnr
emy
ozy
yz
zk
zk
ll
nl
...
```